# Making table row scrollable in Java in Android Stud

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

I tried creating a scroll view in my relative layout to make my table layout scrollable but i keep getting this error:

```js
02-02 19:29:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(9400): 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{test.com.classmanagertest/test.com.classmanagertest.StudentsMasterList}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

This is my Table Layout that display's fields in a database:

```js
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.students_masterlist);
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("ClassManager",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);


        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT StudPic, StudentID, LastName FROM MasterStudents", null);
        int count= c.getCount();
        c.moveToFirst();
        TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
        tableLayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        TableRow tableRow;
        TextView textView, textView1;
        ImageView StudImageView;

        RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
        sv.addView(tableLayout);
        rl.addView(sv);

        for (Integer j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

            StudImageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            StudImageView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            StudImage=c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("StudPic"));
            Bitmap b1= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(StudImage, 0, StudImage.length);
            StudImageView.setImageBitmap(b1);
            tableRow.addView(StudImageView);

            textView1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("StudentID")));
            textView1.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            textView1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blueactionbar));
            textView1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,25);
            textView1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            tableRow.addView(textView1);

            textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("LastName")));
            textView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blueactionbar));
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,25);
            textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            tableRow.addView(textView);
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

            c.moveToNext() ;
        }
        setContentView(tableLayout);
        db.close();
    }
```

This is my xml file:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/layout">



</RelativeLayout>
```

**How do I fix this error?**

Any help is appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: Why are you setting content view twice?And your table view is a child in the scroll view (which is a child of the relative layout).Also when you are setting content view the second time.This also is done on the activity.That is a wrong way to code this

Comment: So i remove the first setcontentview?

Comment: yes and you need to refresh the the overall view.
to do that,Once you add all the rows you call `requestLayout()`

Comment: Can you please write the code? So I can understand it better? I'm new in handling Android Studio.

Comment: its not an android studio issue :)..Ok will add the code.

Comment: I sometimes forget to insert in my post that I'm a newbie at Android. Thanks man!

Comment: @Kreyah.Do you mind if use ListViews etc.Or do you need the same xml code?

Comment: I'm hard understanding listviews. But can table row in my code be clickable or is listviews better? because I want to create a list that's clickable and displays a new form so i can display the rest of the fields of the row? I prefer my code but if its not a bother, can you include your code using list view so i  can understand it. Sorry for the burden friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.students_masterlist);
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("ClassManager",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);


        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT StudPic, StudentID, LastName FROM MasterStudents", null);
        int count= c.getCount();
        c.moveToFirst();
        TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
        tableLayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        TableRow tableRow;
        TextView textView, textView1;
        ImageView StudImageView;

        RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
        sv.addView(tableLayout);
        rl.addView(sv);
        for (Integer j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            StudImageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            StudImageView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            StudImage=c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("StudPic"));
            Bitmap b1= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(StudImage, 0, StudImage.length);
            StudImageView.setImageBitmap(b1);
            tableRow.addView(StudImageView);

            textView1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("StudentID")));
            textView1.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            textView1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blueactionbar));
            textView1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,25);
            textView1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            tableRow.addView(textView1);

            textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("LastName")));
            textView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blueactionbar));
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,25);
            textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            tableRow.addView(textView);
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
            c.moveToNext() ;
        }
        db.close();
        rl.requestLayout();

    }
```

The First setContentView is called with the parenet relative layout which contains the table layout that has your rows.Therefore you are trying to setContentView to a view which is contained in the parent that you have already setContentView to ie.

`rl` contains `sv` contains `tableLayout`.
but you are setting the activity view first to `rl` then to `tableLayout`.

Instead you should set the content view to `rl`.Then fill your tableLayout like you did and refresh the layout.ie call `requestLayout()` on the parent view.

Comment: There is no requestLayout() function. The code turns red.

Comment: call it on your parent view, `rl.requestLayout()`

Comment: I forgot to mention that r.layout.students_masterlist is the xml file relative layout r.id.layout.

Comment: yes that's fine.Also read this for ListView implementation.And ListView would be a way more optimized and easier implementation even to implement click listeners.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: It works thank you! And ill learn that link that you shared. Thanks again!